# Fixed margin in a grouped UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a question related to a UITableView in grouped style. In a special view in my application the table view requires a fixed margin around the table content (sections). The UITableView changes this margin in relation to the table width by default. Now that is my problem. I want to achieve that this margin does NOT change when changing the table width.

I already managed it to set a fixed left/right margin by subclassing UITableViewCell and overriding the layoutSubviews method. But the top/bottom margin is still related to the table width.

Can anyone help me out on this one?

Regards Manu

Answer (score 0):

Probably making table.frame.size.height bigger (and compensating origin.y with half of new height) will do the trick. You should also use table's scrollIndicatorInsets method to fix the scroller position not to go into invisible part.